# why broadcast receiver is not calling service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

In my android app i am calling a service from broadcast receiver.But while debugging  i noticed that broadcast receiver is not working. And there is nothing in main activity like layout or buttons etc

Broadcast receiver class

```
public class Myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    context.startService(i);

}
```

}

And In manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".Myreceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
```

Comment: When should the BroadcastReceiver be triggered ? Have you defined any ACTION programmatically ? I definitely see no ACTION in the manifest.

Comment: What is the action for activate your broadcast?

Comment: You should explicitly define the trigger point in code.

Comment: when actually you want with broadcast receiver? mean which Action..like when user boot complete,charger plug in. which action??

Comment: OK.. Thanks all for quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have registered Broadcast Receiver in your activity

```
    Myreceiver myreceiver = new Myreceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver((BroadcastReceiver) myreceiver, intentFilter);
```